# Show Yes/No-Dialog instead of OK/Cancel

Tags: android

I hate the OK/Cancel dialogs, because if my application ask somebody if (s)he really want to do something you should never answer with "Cancel".

A little example:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
b.setTitle("Hello World");
b.setMessage("Did you do your homework?");
b.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, null);
b.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
b.show();
```

Is it possible that the constants "yes" and "no" really means "yes" and "no" with localization? Or have I do this explicit in my string resource and can't use global constants. So I replace the two lines with:

```
b.setPositiveButton("Yes", null);
b.setNegativeButton("No", null);
```

(or the resources instead of constants here)

Sincerely
xZise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search reveals that there are several apps that do exactly that, including Google's own My Tracks app, so I'd say it's safe to use android.R.string.yes.

Example: http://mytracks.googlecode.com/hg/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/io/backup/ExternalFileBackup.java?r=5ebff81c1c25d9600efb5d88eecc3e068ec22ae9

Comment: Hmmm okay, but where does your example use android.R.string.yes ? And I don't want to know if it is "save", I only want to know how to rename the buttons to Yes/No using constants named like this. Or if I had to add the values manually. I'm not a native english speaker, but is it common to use Ok/Cancel-Dialogs instead of Yes/No-Dialogs? For me it's sounds ugly to answer "Did you done your homework?" with "OK" or "Cancel". Sincerely xZise

Comment: For me, "did you done your homework" sounds ugly :) It's "Did you do your homework". Just search for "android.R.string.yes" in the link I posted. Actually, it changed, check this link here: http://mytracks.googlecode.com/hg/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/io/backup/ExternalFileBackup.java?r=5ebff81c1c25d9600efb5d88eecc3e068ec22ae9

Comment: And to answer your question - you're absolutely right, "Yes" and "No" would be much more appropriate button names, and you'd do the right thing to change them. Windows even has MB_YESNO as an option for its dialogs. Android doesn't, but your code would do the proper thing.

Comment: Hmmm okay thanks, I hoped I only miss some constant. Sincerely xZise

Comment: @EboMike Please update the link as it's not available.

Answer (score 27):

WARNING: `yes` in `android.R.string` has been deprecated.

Maybe was deprecated because it's confusing that the contents of these text resources in English are actually "OK" and "Cancel", **not Yes and No.** So if you need Yes and No, you must use your own string resources. See for example http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3713 and http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/30b589fa9aca185a

Comment: if I have dialog with a message something like _Do you want to download it_? Then _yes / no_ is better. I don't understand why internal string resources `android.R.string.no` and `android.R.string.cancel` both contains word _Cancel_ (doesn't make any sense)

Comment: I think it's really sad that the operating system can't provide localized default responses to dialogs, for the reason that they should be default expressions in every device, for every program, because it's part of the standardized navigation of the device. When developers make their own, they either have to read through a lot of documentation to get all the right answers in each language or they inevitably get it wrong. Bugs that break the default navigation of the devices. Couldn't the OS vendor update the devices instead, so the bug went away?

Answer (score 3):

What you have provided should work.  (An aside, in proper English your question should say "Have you done your homework? Or Did you do your homework?)

I don't think there is any global english standard regarding ok/cancel and yes/no.  It really depends on the context.  There are certain contexts where one or the other would make more sense.  I things it's perfectly OK to use yes/no if that makes more sense for the kinds of things you are asking.